# How do I get Custom Tasks to show up in the tools palette in the Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler?

Tags: eclipse, jbpm, bpmn

I'm trying to define my own work items and work item handlers as described in the [jBPM user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html) on domain specific processes.  It worked once.  When I restarted eclipse they were no longer visible. The bpmn2 files that use my work items still have the properties available in the property view but the tool palette doesn't show the custom task drawer and new jbpmn process diagrams also do not show the custom task drawer.

To try and fix this I have rebuilt my eclipse from scratch (both kepler and luna versions).  Re-added all the jbpm/drools and bpmn2 modeler plugins. Created new jbpmn runtime instances but all with no luck.

I did discover that if I open the diagram with the older version of the bpmn modeler (right-click on the file in eclipse, open with -> BPMN2 Process Editor) then the Service Tasks draw appears with my custom work item but that UI is very difficult to work with when setting attributes and properties.

What do I have to do to re-enable the Custom Tasks drawer in the BPMN2 Diagram Editor?  Everything that I have read just assumes that as long as you have the drools.rulebase.conf file in the META-INF directory of your project with the drools.workDefinitions property in it then the drawer will show up the next time you open a bpmn file.  I did find one bug post [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=396517) that talks about ensuring you use the correct diagram type when creating new but I am already doing that.

My current eclipse environment is:

- Kepler 20140224-0627
- BPMN2 Modeler - Diagram Editor 1.0.5.Final
- JBoss Drools Core 6.2.0.Final
- JBoss jBPM Core 6.2.0.Final

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question on how to create a service task [in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825365/jbpm6-service-task-to-execute-java-code/28832896#28832896). This might help with finding which step you might have missed.

Comment: I reviewed and tried the steps that are different in your other answer and in the user guide and was not successful in getting the palette to show the custom task drawer.  What isn't clear in the other answer is where step 5 is being executed.  It seems to imply running the code somewhere but does say where and how that is supposed to affect things.

Comment: Step 5 would occur anytime you create a session. This is only for registering the workitem so that it executes; which should not affect whether the custom task appears in your palette. If the guides aren't helping, maybe you can edit your post to show what you have done. You might have a file in the wrong location or there could be a typo that is preventing it from working.

Comment: Ah, I thought it must be something like that as it was a snippet from the steps I was already doing when I ran JUnit tests on the jbpm/drools.