# What is the best practice for using EJB interfaces for jBPM serviceTask implementation?

Tags: ejb, jbpm

I use jBPM ver 6.2  and I have no idea how can I solve this. I want to give control for task bean for a EJB container.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusing. Here is an example on [how to implement a Service task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825365/jbpm6-service-task-to-execute-java-code/28832896#28832896). I think that might help.